# Mongo ReplicaSet - Per DB read and write metrics

Tags: mongodb

I have a single Mongo ReplicaSet with ~1,000 Databases. I'm trying to decide how to migrate a subset of these Databases to a second ReplicaSet so that both have roughly equal read/write load.

I would like to do this based on read/write volume per DB. Is mongotop the only way to get these numbers? I'm thinking about running mongotop for a day, parsing it's output per second and storing it into something like Graphite. That way I can look at the reads and writes per DB over an extended period and decide which DBs to migrate.

Is there a better/easier way of doing this?